# Disable post on wall with comment plugin (Facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to disable the "Post to Facebook" function on the comment plugin (See screenshot of function: http://d.pr/i/hPIG).

I've tried almost everything, so maybe someone knows a trick or something that can remove the function or at least uncheck the "Post to Facebook" as default